# Low-pass filter for digital input

Tags: filter, low-pass

I made a digital input circuit to convert a 120Vac waveform into a digital 2.3V signal. I would like to add a "low-pass" filter at the output to **get a low level for higher frequencies than 1kHz**. I can't just use an inverter after a classic low-pass filter because I need to keep the high-low sequence for frequencies below 1kHz.

All suggestions are welcome

**Edit**

What I want below the cutoff frequency :
[image]

What I want above the cutoff frequency :
[image: Output above cutoff frequency]

As you know, a low-pass filter will "smooth" v(OUT) until it becomes a 2.3V DC, and that's what I want to avoid. I want my digital input to be inactive for high frequencies.

Comment: What do you expect your output signal to look like exactly? Is it DC and you are trying to filter out noise higher than 1kHz or...?

Comment: So what you want is a frequency to voltage converter and a comparator at some set point equivalent to the 1kHz frequency. Then that comparator would drive a simple square wave oscillator if the output of the comparator is 1?

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/116623/touch-activated-switch/116626#116626
See my answer there. It's a different application, but beyond the ring oscillator, you have a freq-V conversion and the comparator part of it.

Comment: How much delay can you accept between the digital signal and the analog signal?

Comment: Can you use a simple RC lowpass filter to remove the high frequency noise while passing the line frequency?  Put it ahead of the rectifier.

Comment: Does the "high-low sequence" need to be precisely matched to the input (switching at a particular voltage or phase angle) or would any pulse output do? Does it have to be at the same frequency as the input?

Comment: @BruceAbbott The high-low sequence don't need to be _precisely_ matched to the input. It could have a delay between them, but less than 1ms or 2ms.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a circuit which only lets through pulses with a repetition frequency of less than 1KHz.

When triggered by the leading edge of each input pulse, Monostable IC1 generates a 1ms pulse which clocks D F/F IC3's output high. IC3 is reset when the input pulse goes low again, so the output follows the input. If the frequency is higher than 1KHz then IC1 is continuously triggered and doesn't produce any clock pulses, so IC3 stays in reset.

R2, C2 and IC2B provide a short delay to ensure that IC3 is out of reset when it receives the clock pulse from IC1.

[image: digital 'low pass filter' circuit]

BTW this circuit can be simplified down to just one IC by configuring the other half of the CD4528 as a basic flip-flop. Connect pins 15 and 14 to GND, pin 11 to Vdd, apply clock input (from pin 6) to pin 12, and connect the input frequency direct to pin 4 (+TR) and pin 13 (/RESET). Output is on pin 10.